# Css Border are collapse to each other

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors, shopify-template

I created a caurosal of 8 products when i apply a border than border are joint to each other. i did not create class because all are created dynamically. if i decrease the width the another product that are hide on another caurosal are shown. how i fix it

[image]

```
<div class="flickity-slider" style="left: 0px; transform: translateX(0%);"><div class="carousel-cell is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform: translateX(0%);">
          <a href="/collections/activities-storybooks-kids/products/personalised-goodnight-storybook-girl">
            <img class="img-explore" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0764/5455/products/GOODNIGHT_books-01.jpg?v=1520416066">
            <h4>Personalised Goodnight Storybook - Girl</h4>
            
            <form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="shappify_add_to_cart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product-id="81743151117" id="add-to-cart-form">
              <div class="prices">
                
                <span class="price" itemprop="price">Rs. 1,350</span>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn" id="product-add-to-cart" value="Add to Cart">             
            </form>
          </a>
      </div><div class="carousel-cell is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform: translateX(100%);">
          <a href="/collections/activities-storybooks-kids/products/personalised-goodnight-storybook-boy">
            <img class="img-explore" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0764/5455/products/GOODNIGHT_books-04.jpg?v=1520416051">
            <h4>Personalised Goodnight Storybook - Boy</h4>
            
            <form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="shappify_add_to_cart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product-id="81757011981" id="add-to-cart-form">
              <div class="prices">
                
                <span class="price" itemprop="price">Rs. 1,350</span>     
                
              </div>

              <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn" id="product-add-to-cart" value="Add to Cart">          
              
            </form>
          </a>
      </div><div class="carousel-cell is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform: translateX(200%);">
          <a href="/collections/activities-storybooks-kids/products/stories-for-1-year-olds">
            <img class="img-explore" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0764/5455/products/stories_for_1_yr_old_6e9cdfeb-6ba4-4b57-893d-f0165014e016.jpg?v=1495545024">
            <h4>Stories for 1 year olds</h4>
            <form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="shappify_add_to_cart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product-id="1824342913" id="add-to-cart-form">
              <div class="prices">         
                <span class="price" itemprop="price">Rs. 250</span>    
              </div>       
              <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn" id="product-add-to-cart" disabled="" value="Sold Out">          
              
            </form>
          </a>
      </div><div class="carousel-cell is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform: translateX(300%);">
          <a href="/collections/activities-storybooks-kids/products/my-learning-library-first-words">
            <img class="img-explore" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0764/5455/products/Learning_Library_-_Words.jpg?v=1537694862">
            <h4>My Learning Library - First Words</h4>
            
            <form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="shappify_add_to_cart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product-id="695380246574" id="add-to-cart-form">
              <div class="prices">
                
                <span class="compare-price">Rs. 799</span>
                <span class="price on-sale" itemprop="price">Rs. 599</span>
                
                
              </div>

              
               
              <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn" id="product-add-to-cart" disabled="" value="Sold Out">          
              
            </form>
          </a>
      </div>
```

I tried width property. Select first child and nth of type but that product are hide are shown and first product left side of boundary are hide.

Comment: Can you add CSS for the HTML as well? Even the question is related to CSS, can't find any CSS code snippet apart from inline-CSS.

Comment: https://zt8z32vx5rw3ki6g-7645455.shopifypreview.com in this best seller section

Comment: please add CSS in your question description so that it's visible for community to better answer your question. We can't debug the issue if you pass website links and leave it for us to figure out where the relevant CSS is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code by adding CSS

```
.main_div{
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
/* or  */
.card{
 margin: 0 10px;
}
```